# How do I skip the opening cutscene in Attack the Light?

Tags: steven-universe-attack-the-light

Whenever I open *Steven Universe: Attack the Light* on iOS, I have to wait through a minute and a half of logos and cutscenes before I can start playing.

Is there any way to skip the opening cutscene?

Comment: Without Jailbreaking your phone, I'm willing to bet you can't. And even if you do jailbreak it, you'd probably have to edit the program. This would mean unpacking and decrypting it, editing/removing the videos/logos, then repacking/encrypting it. I'd instead suggest just setting the phone down while it does its thing. Maybe read a magazine or something while you wait.

Comment: I assume you've tried tapping the screen a bunch of times while the intro is playing to see if that will make it skip forward?  I only ask because you didn't say what you've tried already, and that seems like an obvious thing to try.  It may not skip the logos, but it might very well skip the cutscenes.

Comment: @Steve-O Correct. I’ve tried tapping the screen to no effect

Answer (score 1):

Once the logos are done and the cutscene starts playing, escape back to the home screen on your phone. After that, go back into the game and it skips the cutscene and goes straight to the game menu.